# Is there is a way to change a Windows folder icon using a Perl script?

Tags: windows, perl, shell

Is there is a way to change a Windows folder icon using a Perl script?

My intention is to change the ordinary icon of the "xxx_documents" folder to some other icon. I have to run the script in such a way that it takes care for the whole drive.

The drive contains many folders. I have to search for each folder named "documents" (e.g. "xxx_documents" or simply "documents") and change its icon to one from the `"%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll"` library.

Is that possible in Perl? Thanks to all who help me with this.

Answer (score 9):

You sure can do it with Perl.  Windows controls directory icons by use of a hidden system`Dekstop.ini` file in each folder.  The contents looks something like this:

```
 [.ShellClassInfo]
 IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll
 IconIndex=41
```

On Windows XP (and I assume on other systems), icon 41 is a tree.  Windows requires this file be explicitly set as a *system* file for it to work, this means we'll need to dig down into `Win32API::File` to create it:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 use Win32API::File qw(createFile WriteFile fileLastError CloseHandle);

 my $file = createFile(
      'Desktop.ini',
      {
           Access     => 'w',        # Write access
           Attributes => 'hs',       # Hidden system file
           Create     => 'tc',       # Truncate/create
      }
 ) or die "Can't create Desktop.ini - " . fileLastError();

 WriteFile(
      $file,
      "[.ShellClassInfo]\r\n" .
      "IconFile=%SystemRoot%\\system32\\SHELL32.dll\r\n" .
      "IconIndex=41\r\n",
      0, [], []
 ) or die "Can't write Desktop.ini - " . fileLastError();

 CloseHandle($file) or die "Can't close Desktop.ini - " . fileLastError();
```

If you run the code above, it should set the icon for the current directory to a tree.  You may need to refresh your directory listing before explorer picks up the change.

Now that we have a way to change icons, we can now just walk through a whole drive and change every folder that matches our pattern.  We can do this pretty easily with `File::Find`, or one of its alternatives (eg, `File::Find::Rule`, or `File::Next`):

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use File::Find qw(find);
 use Win32API::File qw(createFile WriteFile fileLastError CloseHandle);

 my $topdir = $ARGV[0] or die "Usage: $0 path\n";

 find( \&changeIcon, $topdir);

 sub changeIcon {
     return if not /documents$/i;   # Skip non-documents folders
     return if not -d;              # Skip non-directories.

     my $file = createFile(
         "$_\\Desktop.ini",
         {
              Access     => 'w',        # Write access
              Attributes => 'hs',       # Hidden system file
              Create     => 'tc',       # Truncate/create
         }
     ) or die "Can't create Desktop.ini - " . fileLastError();

     WriteFile(
         $file,
         "[.ShellClassInfo]\r\n" .
         "IconFile=%SystemRoot%\\system32\\SHELL32.dll\r\n" .
         "IconIndex=41\r\n",
         0, [], []
     ) or die "Can't write Desktop.ini - " . fileLastError();

     CloseHandle($file) or die "Can't close Desktop.ini - " . fileLastError();
 }
```

Unfortunately, I've just discovered that the icon *only* gets changed if the directory currently has, or once had, an icon...  There's clearly an attribute that's being set on the directory itself that causes Windows to look for a `Desktop.ini` file, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.  As such, the above solution is incomplete; we also need to find and fix the attributes on the directory where we're adding the icon.

*Paul*

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144102.aspx you also need to set the system attribute on the containing folder.

Answer (score 2):

1.

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21790
InfoTip=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-12689
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-108
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-237
```

2.

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21803
InfoTip=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-12689
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-3
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the icon to refresh, you will have to invoke some SHChangeNotify voodoo (C++ example, but you get the idea):

```
int imageIndex = Shell_GetCachedImageIndexW(wPath, GetSyncFolderIconIndex(), 0);
if (imageIndex != -1)
{
    // If we don't do this, and we EVER change our icon, Explorer will likely keep
    // using the old one that it's already got in the system cache.
    SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEIMAGE, SHCNF_DWORD | SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, &imageIndex, NULL);
}
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATHW | SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT, wPath, NULL);
```